# alter "required" property of the form element in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms, form-api, hook-form-alter

I have some require fields in some form,I want them  be required in somewhere and in another place not be required (I want exactly them , maybe you suggest me use existance field in cck but this  fields not in cck.)
I used profile2 module with some profile type, I want in profile type edit page as example `name` field be required and in user registration `name` field not be required.
I try to alter `#require` property of `name` field in form alter, it's changed correctly  but in validation tell me the `name` field is required.

in

```
      function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state) {
            if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
              $form['profile_detailp']['field_name']['und']['#required']=0;
              ...
              }

      }
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is ok, and have to works but maybe in another module  it `require` again.

```
     function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state) {
        if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
          $form['profile_detailp']['field_name']['und']['#required']=0;
          ...
          }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Text field need do it like this

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['profile_detailp']['field_name']['und'][0]['value']['#required']=0;
  }
}
```